# Отцентрировать изображение по вертикали HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

```css
* {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
#header {
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100%;
 background-image: url('https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTqo7F5-ChUGOn7NF_7AfxQ6HLkwzjU5avVAZSAmWYfK6mFqQFj');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 100%;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.mw {
 max-width: 1190px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

#header_nav {
 position: absolute;
 width: 1190px;
 height: 90px;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 margin: 35px auto;
 background: #fff;
}
#header_nav img {
 position: relative;
 margin: auto 10px;
    height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Umbrella</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="header_nav">
  <img src="https://www.google.com/photos/about/static/images/google.svg">
 </div>
 
 <div id="header">
  <div class="mw">
   
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Как мне отцентрировать картинку "Google"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Вариант 1** (`vertical-align: middle; text-align: center;`):

```css
* {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
#header {
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100%;
 background-image: url('https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTqo7F5-ChUGOn7NF_7AfxQ6HLkwzjU5avVAZSAmWYfK6mFqQFj');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 100%;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.mw {
 max-width: 1190px;
    width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

#header_nav {
 position: absolute;
 max-width: 1190px;
    width: 100%;
 height: 90px;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 margin: 35px auto;
 background: #fff;
  
  text-align: center;
}
#header_nav:before{
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}
#header_nav img {
   vertical-align: middle;
 position: relative;
 margin: auto 10px;
    height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Umbrella</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="header_nav">
  <img src="https://www.google.com/photos/about/static/images/google.svg">
 </div>
 
 <div id="header">
  <div class="mw">
   
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Тоже, но без псевдоэлемента**:

```css
* {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
#header {
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100%;
 background-image: url('https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTqo7F5-ChUGOn7NF_7AfxQ6HLkwzjU5avVAZSAmWYfK6mFqQFj');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 100%;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.mw {
 max-width: 1190px;
    width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

#header_nav {
 position: absolute;
 max-width: 1190px;
    width: 100%;
 height: 90px;
  line-height: 90px;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 margin: 35px auto;
 background: #fff;
  
  text-align: center;
}

#header_nav img {
 position: relative;
 margin: auto 10px;
    height: 60px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Umbrella</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="header_nav">
  <img src="https://www.google.com/photos/about/static/images/google.svg">
 </div>
 
 <div id="header">
  <div class="mw">
   
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Вариант 2** (flex):

```css
* {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
#header {
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100%;
 background-image: url('https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTqo7F5-ChUGOn7NF_7AfxQ6HLkwzjU5avVAZSAmWYfK6mFqQFj');
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: 100%;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.mw {
 max-width: 1190px;
    width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

#header_nav {
 position: absolute;
 max-width: 1190px;
    width: 100%;
 height: 90px;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 margin: 35px auto;
 background: #fff;
  
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

#header_nav img {
 position: relative;
 margin: auto 10px;
    height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Umbrella</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="header_nav">
  <img src="https://www.google.com/photos/about/static/images/google.svg">
 </div>
 
 <div id="header">
  <div class="mw">
   
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

`#header_nav` - `line-height: 90px;`

`#header_nav img` - `vertical-align: middle;`

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#header {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url('https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTqo7F5-ChUGOn7NF_7AfxQ6HLkwzjU5avVAZSAmWYfK6mFqQFj');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.mw {
  max-width: 1190px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#header_nav {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1190px;
  height: 90px;
  line-height: 90px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 35px auto;
  background: #fff;
}
#header_nav img {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto 10px;
  height: 60px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="header_nav">
  <img src="https://www.google.com/photos/about/static/images/google.svg">
</div>

<div id="header">
  <div class="mw">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

В стили `#header_nav img` добавьте

```
#header_nav img {
    top: calc(50% - 30px);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

добавить к #header_nav
**display: flex**

или, т.к. у вас фиксированная высота картинки и родительского блока

```
#header_nav img {
position: relative; 
height: 60px;
margin-top: 45px;
top: -30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#header {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url('https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTqo7F5-ChUGOn7NF_7AfxQ6HLkwzjU5avVAZSAmWYfK6mFqQFj');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.mw {
  max-width: 1190px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#header_nav {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1190px;
  height: 90px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 35px auto;
  background: #fff;
  vertical-align: middle
}
#header_nav img {
  margin: auto 10px;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Umbrella</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header_nav">
    <img src="https://www.google.com/photos/about/static/images/google.svg">
  </div>

  <div id="header">
    <div class="mw">

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```